# Replace character

Tags: c, string, char

I've done this code so far but I don't get a final output (blank).
Output that I expected is when I put a string `Hello World` and replace `o` with `i` the string will be `Helli Wirld`. But I got nothing in the final output.

```
char * substitute(char *, char, char);

int main(void){

  char arr[255];
  char i,j;
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  gets(arr);
  printf("Find a char: ");
  scanf(" %c", &i);
  printf("Replace with: ");
  scanf(" %c", &j);
  printf("Final output: ");
  printf("%s", substitute(arr, i, j));
  return 0;
}

char * substitute(char *data, char find, char replace){
  while(*data!='\0'){
   if(*data==find){
   *data=replace;
   }
  data++;
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to the end of the string.

Comment: @Wooble in the function? isn't that I replace the character?

Comment: You do replace the character in the original string, but then you don't return a pointer to the start of the string, but rather to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `substitute()` you return the pointer `data` that you have incremented in your `while` loop, so now it points to the terminating `'\0'` and that's what you `printf()`.

You could either use a separate local variable for traversing the string, or you don't use the return value of `substitute()` at all and replace

```
printf("%s", substitute(arr, i, j));
```

by

```
substitute(arr, i, j);
printf("%s", arr );
```